# WorkManager's uniqueWorkName in different apps

Tags: android, android-workmanager

[WorkManager#enqueueUniquePeriodicWork](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(java.lang.String,%20androidx.work.ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy,%20androidx.work.PeriodicWorkRequest)) have parameter **uniqueWorkName**.

> Only one PeriodicWorkRequest of a particular name can be active at a
>   time

Will it collides with another Apps? i.e. will two apps, that schedule work with same name replace each other's work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will it collide with another Apps? i.e. will two apps, that schedule work with same name replace each other's work?

Each app runs in its own "sandbox",  there will be no interference from other apps. The name has to be unique *within your package* because ...

> The uniqueWorkName uniquely identifies this PeriodicWorkRequest.

(quoted from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(java.lang.String,%20androidx.work.ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy,%20androidx.work.PeriodicWorkRequest)) on `WorkManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork()` )

The only thing which has to be unique as far as other apps are concerned is the package name: it's impossible to have two apps with the same package name installed simultaneously. But components within one package can be named like components in another package.(I guess there are thousands of apps out there with a MainActivity)